# What are good examples of computational theories for A.I. according to David Marr's Definition?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, learning-theory

I was reading David Marr's ["Artificial Intelligence-A Personal View"](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/5776) and he talks about "computational theory of AI" or what he laters labels as "Type 1" Theory. He provides the example of Chomsky's notion of "competence theory for English syntax as an example of what he means by that. However, with the current trend of deep learning and modern machine learning, that example seems quite different and very unfamiliar.

Is there a better example with more modern AI like machine learning (or deep learning)? Even if it were at least from 1 layer models like Support Vector Machine (SVM) or Radial Basis Functions Networks (RBFs), but something that was modern? What is an example of type 1 theory in modern AI?